# Showing Legend on the side of graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I plotted a graph and the legend is showing right on top of the graph there by hiding the graph.

How can I show it on the side.

Here is the code I wrote

```
##############################################################################
# Plot ROC curves for the multiclass problem

# Compute macro-average ROC curve and ROC area

# First aggregate all false positive rates
all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

# Then interpolate all ROC curves at this points
mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
for i in range(n_classes):
    mean_tpr += interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

# Finally average it and compute AUC
mean_tpr /= n_classes

fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

# Plot all ROC curves
plt.figure()
plt.plot(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"],
label='micro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["micro"]),
         linewidth=2)

plt.plot(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"],
label='macro-average ROC curve (area = {0:0.2f})'
               ''.format(roc_auc["macro"]),
         linewidth=2)

for i in range(n_classes):
    plt.plot(fpr[i], tpr[i], label='AUC class {0} (area = {1:0.2f})'
                                   ''.format(i, roc_auc[i]))

plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], 'k--')
plt.xlim([0.0, 1.0])
plt.ylim([0.0, 1.05])
plt.xlabel('False Positive Rate')
plt.ylabel('True Positive Rate')
plt.title('Multi-Class ROC Curve of '+name)
plt.legend(loc="lower right")
```

And here is the image I got.

[image]

Comment: Look at these examples: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to put the legend out of a graph, is to de zoom on the graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in xrange(5):
    ax.plot(x, i * x, label='$y = %ix$'%i)

# Shrink current axis by 20%
box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

# Put a legend to the right of the current axis
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5))

plt.show()
```

[image]